# Android: Is there a uses-feature option for the sd card?

Tags: android, manifest

Some of the newer devices coming out from Google do not include an sd card, and it appears they are moving towards this direction.

My question: Is there a way to declare the sd card as a uses-feature to prevent people without an external storage from seeing/downloading the app from Google Play?

I realize this is not the correct way to address the issue, but until i can re-code my apps to anticipate this, I am hoping there is a filtering option in the manifest?

Comment: Those devices have external storage.  They're just not physically available to the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `<uses-feature>` which does what you want.

What you could do is manually select the devices within your developer dashboard on Google Play. I know this is very inefficient and will probably take a lot of time but it's the only way of achieving exactly what you want.

If you don't want to bother with that then i would recommend that you include this information in your app's description on Google Play and on top of that handle the situation when your application is started up for the first time (for example inform the user that the device is not supported because it has no external storage).

Comment: Paul: Thanks for the info. I'll have to alert users on the app description and deal with random comments until i sort it out.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if such a feature exists, and even if it did it would be difficult to use. I have a Samsung Galaxy Nexus, and while it doesn't have an SD card per-say, it does have 16GB of internal storage. I have seen other phones that say "Internal SD Card" so it really depends on whether that feature (if it exists) can tell the difference between the two. Some devices also have an actual SD card that's hidden from the user, and so they aren't able to tell it's there. Most devices now also have a decent amount of internal storage, so I'm not sure why it's an issue. Do you even need to re-code your application for that? I would think that android would realize that you're requesting storage space that's unavailable and would tell notify the user that they need more storage. All android phones have some amount of internal storage available to the user.

Comment: will a call to Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() work as normal if the storage is internal? Or will it cause an exception? If you're saying I don't need to recode then i'm assuming this call will work as expected?

Comment: That will work fine. Because `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` returns what the manufacturer considers to be "external storage". As far as I know, that `getExternalStorageDirectory()` should always return something, even if an external SD card is not present. The manufacturer can't elect to skip having an External Storage Directory, it's a requirement. So you should not get an exception when you call that. That being said, I would do as much testing as possible. You may still need to get optimal behavior.