# manifest <uses-feature> does not contain External Storage Support

Tags: android, android-manifest

"uses-feature" in manifest does not contain External Storage Support.

I use google drive api. This api require external storage.

I want to block installation of external-storage-unsupported device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There is no  which does what you want.

picked from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12040442/2683275)

if at all you only want the drive to be stored in the sdcard/external memory then you could add an `installLocation` attribute to the manifest specifying `preferExternal`

Answer (score 0):

did you mean this?

> :uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"

you can check this link
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html